# Device(Xiaoma Poco f1) is not detecting Android Studio through USB

Tags: android-studio, usb

Device is not detecting Androidstudio via USB
I have tried below the possible solutions

1.Checking the virtualization (It is enabled)

2.Disable driver signature from BIOS settings

3.Changed the Platform tools from Android SDK

4.Disabling "Turn on MIUI Optimisation" in mobile Developer options

None of the above options are working.
I am checking on this since 4 days.I have to resolve as soon as possible.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.